"Non-random" non-trivial structure in the prime numbers
For heuristically answering questions about prime numbers, it is often (?) useful to use a model that goes something like "each number $n$ is prime independently with probability $1/\log(n)$". This model predicts that there are bounded gaps between primes, it predicts that there are about $N/\log(N)$ primes below $N$, it predicts arbitrarily long arithmetic progressions in primes, it predicts (in the absence of small counterexamples) that Goldbach's conjecture is true with very high probability.
Of course this model gets some very trivial things wrong. It predicts that $n$ and $n + 1$ are both prime for infinitely many $n$; it predicts that the final base 10 digit of a prime is uniformly distributed over all 10 digits; it predicts infinitely primes that are perfect powers.
However, all of the examples I just gave actually are trivial: $n$ and $n+1$ can't both be odd; the final digit of a prime $> 7$ must be from $1, 3, 7, 9$; and a perfect power can never be prime. And indeed, once you "correct" for these trivialities, these become theorems or widely believed conjectures: $n, n+1$ can't both be prime unless $n=2$, but we believe that $n, n+2$ infinitely often are; Dirichlet's theorem tells us that the final digits $1, 3, 7, 9$ all occur infinitely often (in fact, all about equally often); and although $n^k$ ($k \geq 2$) can't be prime, we predict that $n^k + 1$ is prime infinitely often.
And I can't think of any others! As far as I've been able to think of, every fact or widely believed conjecture about the primes is either trivial, or is a statement that has an element of "the primes behave the same way you would predict from a random sequence".
So my question is: what are examples of theorems about the primes (or otherwise widely believed conjectures) which do not fall into either of those categories?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%27s_conjecture

This is discussed in great detail by Terence Tao here: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2015/01/04/254a-supplement-4-probabilistic-models-and-heuristics-for-the-primes-optional/

Consider, for $p$ is prime $\ge 5$ then $p^2-1$ is multiple of $24$.

@QiaochuYuan, thank you for this link -- it gives a higher quality and more in-depth answer than I could possibly expect on MSE (although I did get a perfectly good one here, too).

@m-stgt, that comes from the fact that $p=6k-1$ and $p=6k+1$. so $11^2-1=120$ and $120/24=5$ and $13^2-1=168$ so $168/24=7$ to give just two examples.

@user25406 -- No need for primes, also odd number which are not multiple of $3$ show this characteristic. E.g. $35^2=1225=51*24+1$. There's a clip with two explanations, I link to the end of the 1st to save time and -- one explanation is sufficient me think.

@m-stgt,$35=57=(6i-1)(6j+1)$ with $i=j=1$. So $35^2=(6i-1)^2*(6j+1)^2$. The squaring of $(6i-1)$ gets rid of the $-1$ so we end up with $35^2-1=1225-1=1224$ and $1224/24=24*51$.

The random model of the primes that you're describing, where $x$ is prime with probability $1/\log x$, is known as Cramer's Model. It gives good predictions for many questions, but there are some important cases where it fails, and not just for the "trivial" cases you outlined.
A good example is Maier's Theorem, which I will describe a special case of.
Let's define $f(x)$ to be the ratio between the number of primes in an interval of length $\log^2 x$, and the expected number of primes in that interval under Cramer's model, namely $\log x$:
$$f(x) := \frac{\pi(x+\log^2(x))-\pi(x)}{\log x}$$
Maier's Theorem concerns the limsup and liminf of $f(x)$. Cramer's model predicts that the limsup and liminf are both 1, almost surely. Maier proved in 1985 that in fact the limsup of $f(x)$ is greater than 1, and the liminf is less than 1.
The proof is in this paper: Primes in Short Intervals, by Helmut Maier,
Michigan Math. J. 32(2): 221-225 (1985).
More generally, Maier showed that if we generalize the function $f(x)$ to examine primes in intervals of length $\log^\lambda(x)$, for any $\lambda \ge 2$, the limsup and liminf are always above and below 1 respectively, and Cramer's model always gets it wrong.
$$f_\lambda(x) := \frac{\pi(x+\log^\lambda(x))-\pi(x)}{\log^{\lambda-1} x}$$
This case where Cramer's model gets it wrong also has a bunch of secondary consequences, such as when it comes to predictions about the sizes of prime gaps. Granville's heuristics on prime gaps are now considered more plausible than Cramer's, for this reason.
